swaCli does not produce error and does not deploy
Attached is the screenshot of the cli. As you can see, the command did not upload to azure, yet did not produce errors. Azure has no records of failed deployment. Does anyone know where to start looking for this?
Screenshot of swa cli
Here's the steps:

I ensured the app worked by building it with npm run build.
swa build
swa deploy using the commands in the screenshot.

I'm expecting to either find errors related to this so I can eventually upload the app to azure static web apps.

Can you share code in text format? @emt2dev


swa Cli does not produce error and does not deploy:

It is a very transient that might occur due to some environment reasons. Try and check below points to resolve the issue.
Need to check below:

Check config.json file of static web apps again and verify all the settings and dependencies are properly configured.
To get more transparent details on the error or deployment stuck issue, use --verbose=silly flag along with the swa deploy command.
Check the deployment in Portal to know the status of it whether it is succeeded or created or failed.

I have created a sample static web app configuration and tried to build it withswa build. It worked as expected.

Note: If still the issue persists, clear the cache in your environment and try deployment in another environment or folder path.
Refer common issues related to your conflict.

This worked for me: https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps-cli/issues/591#issuecomment-1287651863. Here, problem was deploying with --app-location as . and not any folder like public. Based on question and description, this could be potential solution but given the author of question already uses folder path, I am adding this as a comment to add to common issues / solutions.
